# Vim regex of correct json string

Tags: regex, json, vim

Does this vim regex match only correct JSON strings?
Does it match every correct JSON string?
Quotes are part of regex.

```
"\([^\\"]\|\\\(u\x\{4}\|["trf\\bn/]\)\)*"
```

UPD: I need JSON string objects ("...").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my eyes the regex corresponds to the syntax diagram (see below) from http://www.json.org .
IMO your regexp should only match correct JSON strings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** after update: The regex looks ok to me.

Comment: I mean only string, not list, object or smth else.